# Replace function queries

Tags: c#

I've been trying to create a battleships game. Its my first time coding so I'm trying to learn the best and most efficient ways of writing it.

Basically my issue at the moment is I have a string called `A1` through to `A10`, I've got some code that randomly selects `A1` - `A10`. What I want to happen is when a coordinate is selected i.e. `A5`, it will then change the value of `A5` to either X or H but I'm having issues doing this.

I've tried using `A1.Replace("0", "1")` just as a test but it does not work.

```cs
var A1 = "0";
var A2 = "0";
var A3 = "0";
var A4 = "0";
var A5 = "0";
var A6 = "0";
var A7 = "0";
var A8 = "0";
var A9 = "0";
var A10 = "0";

string[] DestroyerC = { "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4","A5","A6","A7",A8","A9",A10"};

// Create a Random object  
Random rand = new Random();
// Generate a random index less than the size of the array.  
int index = rand.Next(DestroyerC.Length);

var CoordinatesD1 = ($"{DestroyerC[index]}");

string letters = string.Empty;
string numbers = string.Empty;

foreach (char c in CoordinatesD1)
{
    if (Char.IsLetter(c))
    {
        letters += c;
    }
    if (Char.IsNumber(c))
    {
        numbers += c;
    }
}

int number = int.Parse(numbers);

String Ship1 = CoordinatesD1;
String Ship2 = (letters + (number + 1));
String Ship3 = (letters + (number + 2));
String Ship4 = (letters + (number + 3));

// Enter Code A1, A2, A3

String Shot;

Shot = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

// Hit or Miss
if (Shot == CoordinatesD1)
{
    BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
    WriteLine("Hit!");
    Console.ResetColor();
    // Replace Sting with new value
    A1.Replace("0","X");
}
else
{
    BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    WriteLine("Miss!");
    Console.ResetColor();
    A1.Replace("0","M");
```

So what I want to happen in this code is when the player enters a code i.e. `A1` I then want the string `A1` to change from 0 to either X (for Hit) and M (for miss). Is there a way I can link all these codes under 1 string or is there a way that I can easily replaces these if the sting value is typed in?

Comment: You may want to have a quick peek at arrays before moving too far into this project.

Comment: In order that to get replaced string you should do that: A1 = A1.Replace("0", "M");
string is immutable. You can't edit string, only create new instance.

Comment: This sounds like a great first project.  After your code is fully implemented, I would encourage you to make use of [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 8):

Variables *vary* -- that's why they're called variables -- and the way you make a variable change is by using the assignment operator `=`.  If you want A1 to become "1" just say

```
A1 = "1";
```

> I've tried using `A1.Replace("0", "1")` just as a test but it does not work.

That is a common beginner mistake that is occasionally made by experts as well.  `Replace` does not *mutate* anything. `Replace` *produces* a new string that has the replacement.  So `A1.Replace(whatever)` means "make the replacement and then ignore it".  Had you said

```
A1 = A1.Replace("0", "1");
```

then you would have gotten what you intended, but that is a far too complicated way to just say

```
A1 = "1".
```

Incidentally, today would be a great day to learn about arrays and lists.  Your code would more conventionally be written:

```
var locations = new List<string>{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"};
```

or

```
var locations = new []{"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"};
```

and now instead of `A1 = whatever;` you say `locations[0] = whatever;`.  Lists and arrays give you a set of numbered locations starting at zero.  (The difference is that an array -- the second example -- does not allow you to change the number of elements in it, but a `List<string>` does.)

Comment: Or, better yet, use a `byte` or `bool` array instead of strings.

Comment: @JonathanWood: I take your point but that is still *primitive obsession*. If the problem is to represent one of a small, finite set, an enumeration would be the more standard way to go. As would encoding a 2-d coordinate as a tuple, not a string.

Comment: I'm trying to create a grid so I've created strings for each individual square. Is there a way I can use the list example you've provided above Eric and use it to replace my 100 strings, and would I then be able to replace the values so it changes from 0 to x etc?

Comment: @EricLippert: I take your point.  However, coordinates represent positions, so I would use a pair of ints inside of a readonly `Point`, rather than an enumeration.  Mapping those the dimensions to characters is more of an I/O issue than an appropriate internal representation.

Comment: As an aside, so long as nobody ever actually renders the game board and so long as nobody cares about detecting erroneous inputs by users, you could totally get away with making strings your position system and have those strings not actually be mapped to an underlying grid.  I feel like that's a bad idea for a learning project and also a bad idea for a production project, but I can see how a new programmer could end up doing so accidentally and then not having an easy way to fix users who create ships on non-contiguous positions.

Comment: @ItsOliMate: Absolutely there is! And I am a big fan of beginners learning the right way to do things early on. But there is also an argument to be made for walking before you try to run. But keep on having those thoughts, particularly: *Is there a way to make the code read more like the underlying concept* and *is there an operation that I can move to a class or method that does that operation?*  Repeatedly applying those two principles is how we end up with understandable code.

Answer (score 0):

My post is not answer for your question. But if you want to write correct code than you have to understand how to move a task into the code that can be easily understood by another developer.

As I right understand your battleships game, it is game at `NxN` field. So it is the best way (in my opinion) to use `NxN` array (two-dimensional array with `N` columns and `N` rows) to describe a battlefield. For example, here you can use

- `0` for cell where there is no ship
- `1` for cell where there is alive ship
- `-1` for cell where there is destroyed (wounded) ship

Another way, you can create such class:

```
class Ship
{
    public string Name {get;set;} // name of ship (single desk ship, double desk ship etc.)
    public string[] Alive {get;set;} //alive cell of ship, if length of this array is zero, then ship is destroyed
    public string[] Destroyed {get;set;} //destroyed cell of ship
}
```

This class will be describe all ships at battlefield. For example, double desk ship:

```
var doubleDeskShip = new Ship
{
   Name = "Double desk ship 1",
   Alive = new string[] {"A1", "B1"}
}
```

It is not full algorithm for your task, but it is some idea that may be useful for you.